# How to write a generic ISort interface?

Tags: c#, generics, sorting, interface

I'd like to create various sorting classes (QuickSort, MergeSort, BucketSort...etc).
I have a common Interface (ISort).

This interface has a method:

```
Collection<T> Sort(Collection<T> list);
```

Now when im trying to use a class it seems like i have to declare like this:

```
ISort<char> sort = new QuickSort();
```

The QuickSort implementation looks like this:

```
public class QuickSort : ISort<char>
    {
        public Collection<char> Sort(Collection<char> list)
        {
            // TODO: implement this.
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This implementation is what i dont like because the T template is a char.
How can i keep this class generic so that i can use this class to sort an int, float, double, char...etc?

Comment: BTW: if you've got QuickSort, why do you need the others ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like this:

```
public class QuickSort<T> : ISort<T>
    {
        public Collection<T> Sort(Collection<T> list)
        {
            // TODO: implement this.
            return null;
        }
    }
```

with

```
ISort<char> sort = new QuickSort<char>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting has nothing to do with the data type in the collection being sorted so you shouldn't force a type parameter at the class level. Also you will need to compare objects so they should implement IComparable.

You could design the interface like this and avoid tying the instance of the sorting class to the type it will sort:

```
interface ISort
{
    ICollection<T> Sort<T>(ICollection<T> collection) where T : IComparable<T>;
}

class QuickSort : ISort
{
    public ICollection<T> Sort<T>(ICollection<T> collection) where T : IComparable<T>
    {
        Comparer<T> comparer = Comparer<T>.Default;
        // TODO: Implement
        return collection;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the same sorting object for all data types. The one drawback to this design, is that you won't be able to store state that is specific based on the generic type parameter. So QuickSort couldn't contain fields that use the generic type paremeter T.